# How to get Enterprise Logging to roll file using Fluent API?

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, enterprise-library

For the life of me, even after reviewing various similar topics via google searches and StackOverflow questions, I simply can't get my log file to work. Below is my code -- can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It write to the file no problem, but to the exact same file.

Thanks!

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_have_log_files_roll_using_fluent_api()
    {

        // specify the target log file name and path
        string rootDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LogFilePath");
        string logTemplate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LogTemplate"); // e.g. <add key="LogTemplate" value="{timestamp(local:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff)} {severity} | {title} - {message}"/>
        string logFileFullPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, "sample_rolling_file.log");

        // configure logging using Fluent API
        var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureLogging()
            .WithOptions
                .DoNotRevertImpersonation()
            .LogToCategoryNamed("Basic")
                .WithOptions
                    .SetAsDefaultCategory()
                .SendTo.RollingFile("Rolling Flat File Trace Listener")
                    .WhenRollFileExists(RollFileExistsBehavior.Increment)
                    .RollEvery(RollInterval.Minute)
                    .RollAfterSize(1000) // 1000 kb
                    .WithTraceOptions(TraceOptions.None)
                    .UseTimeStampPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    .ToFile(logFileFullPath)
                    .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
                                .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
                                .UsingTemplate(logTemplate))
            ;

        // override the default .config file configuration to use above configuration
        var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
        builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);

        EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current
              = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);

        // create a new instance of the logger 
        LogWriter logger = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();
        // LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configSource);
        // _logWriter = logWriterFactory.Create();


        //--- TEST WRITING

        string category = "Basic";
        TraceEventType severity = TraceEventType.Information;
        string message = "START";
        string title = "Unit Test";

        logger.Write(message, category, 1, 0, severity, title);
        string content = File.ReadAllText(logFileFullPath);
        content.Should().Contain("START");

        DateTime stopWritingTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
        while (DateTime.Now < stopWritingTime)
        {
            message = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
            logger.Write(message, category, 1, 0, severity, title);
            Thread.Sleep(900);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks fine.

However, the line:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(logFileFullPath);
```

is throwing an exception so you are only writing one log entry per test.  When the log file is opened it is locked so you won't be able to read it using File.ReadAllText.

You can read through the lock using something like:

```
string fileContents = null;
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();        
}
```